# asp.net identity mvc front end

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, roles

I need to build a front end that will allow me to add users and roles to an MVC 5 application.

I'm surprised to find that there is nothing built in and I'm struggling to find anything thats pre-built that I can plug-in.

Can anyone make any suggestions on where or what I should be searching for.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After more searching I've found the following:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Customizing-ASPNET-Authentication-with-Identity/01
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Customizing-ASPNET-Authentication-with-Identity/02
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Customizing-ASPNET-Authentication-with-Identity/03

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc

The above should give enough information for a newb like me to get started down the route of asp.net identity.